# SI Publish-subscribe channel - parallel or sequential execution?

Tags: spring-integration

I create a publish-subscribe channel like

```
@Bean
MessageChannel parallelRunningSubscribableChannel() {
    return MessageChannels.publishSubscribe("parallelRunningSubscribableChannel").get();
}
```

My main flow ends with this channel and 2 other flows start with that:

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow mainFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows
            .from(...)
            ...
            .channel(parallelRunningSubscribableChannel)
            .get();
}

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow subFlow1() {
    return flow -> flow.channel(parallelRunningSubscribableChannel())
            .handle(...)
            ...
}

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow subFlow2() {
    return flow -> flow.channel(parallelRunningSubscribableChannel())
            .handle(...)
            ...
}
```

I presume the subFlow1 and subFlow2 runs sequentially (e.g. first subFlow1 runs and then subflow2), is that correct?
I'd need to know if a new thread is created as I'd want to the 2 subflows run in the same db transaction.

Just out of curiosity how could I make the 2 subflows run parallel?

Thank you!

Regards,
V.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `PublishSubscribeChannel` is not concurrent by default. See docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#channel-implementations-publishsubscribechannel

To make those subscribers to work in parallel, in their own threads, you need to configure a `TaskExecutor` for this channel explicitly.

> I'd want to the 2 subflows run in the same db transaction.

If you make them parallel, they are going to work in their own threads therefor they can't participate in the same TX.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification!